# Running Hive Using Scala As a Script

Tags: scala, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I was going through the processBuilder API of Scala, In order to run shell commands like we run in Shell Script, I could run few scripts but Having an issue with one type of Hive query execution.

When I run the below commands it was running success fully, but one type of format fails:

### Running Shell Command(Successful):

```
scala> import sys.process._
scala> "ls -lrt /home/cloudera/Desktop".!
total 164
-rwxrwxr-x  1 cloudera cloudera    237 Apr  5  2016 Parcels.desktop
-rwxrwxr-x  1 cloudera cloudera    238 Apr  5  2016 Kerberos.desktop
-rwxrwxr-x  1 cloudera cloudera    259 Apr  5  2016 Express.desktop
```

### Running Hive Query With File Option(Successful):

```
 scala> "hive -f /home/cloudera/hi.hql" !!
 warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for 
 details
 ls: cannot access /usr/lib/spark/lib/spark-assembly-*.jar: No such 
 file or directory
 2017-09-03 23:20:34,392 WARN  [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: The 
 hbase-prefix-tree module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not 
 present.  Continuing without it.

 Logging initialized using configuration in 
 file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
 OK
Time taken: 0.913 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
res20: String =
"100    Amit                    12000   10
 101    Allen                   22000   20 .                                   

"
```

### Running Hive Query With -e Option(Failed):

If i had the run the below query on the terminal I could run in the below given Format.

```
bash$ hive -e "select * staging.from employee_canada;"
```

The problem while running the same query in scala terminal fails because of the double quotes ("") @ the Select query. How can I escape those and run successfully. Tried using  triple quotes and as well as escape "\" sequence but still failed to execute.

```
scala> "hive -e select * staging.from employee_canada; "!!
```

### Below is the Error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:6 cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' 
'<EOF>' '<EOF>' in select clause
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 64
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp
at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(
ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:102)
... 32 elided
```

Comment: The hive -e options works when used with the sequence type Process Builder.

   [answer] val results = Seq("hive", "-e", "select * from staging.employee_canada;").!!

Comment: You answer below, not in the comments